# fopen shows invalid characters at the beginning of csv

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have this code in php which opens a CSV file, reads the first line into an array and shows the content:

```
if (($tmp = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $firstLine = fgetcsv($tmp, 0, ",");
    print_r($firstLine);
}
```

The problem is that the printed array shows `Array ( [0] => ï»¿increment_id...`
Where it should be `Array ( [0] => increment_id...`.
I don't know where those first characters come from, since they are not present when I open the csv file with *Notepad++*. I guess I could convert the file to another encoding, but that would be difficult, since it's the output of a program I didn't make, unless there's a way to re-encode it with PHP.

Comment: The file has a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning.

Comment: It is the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (byte-order-mark) encoded as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8). It is present in the file but the text editors don't show it (technically, it is a non-printable character) but use it to learn about the encoding of the characters in file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Notepad++ open that file, than go to **"Encoding"** menu, than choose **"Encode in UTF-8"**. Save the file. Those 3 bytes will be gone.

Or you could do like this:

```
file_put_contents($file, str_replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF", "", file_get_contents($file)));
if (($tmp = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
  $firstLine = fgetcsv($tmp, 0, ",");
  print_r($firstLine);
}
```

this will remove UTF-8 Signature from file.

Comment: ok =) try this: `$firstLine = fgetcsv(str_replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF", "", $tmp), 0, ",");`

Comment: True! Totally forget about this =). One moment please.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are reading and parsing the file as CSV directly. Change the approach: read the file as string then parse the string as CSV, example :

```
<?php
/*$file = "test.csv";
if (($tmp = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $firs= fgetcsv($tmp, 0, ",");
    print_r($firstLine);
}*/
$handle = fopen( "test.csv", "r" );
$line = fgets( $handle );          // GET FIRST LINE IN FILE.
$line = str_getcsv( $line, "," );  // PARSE LINE AS CSV.
print_r( $line );
?>
```